# What is the difference between creating a Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm working on Notification and have seen two different ways of creating a notification object, hopefully someone can help explain the difference between the two methods?

Ex.1

```
Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID").build();
```

EX.2

```
NotificationCompat.Builder myNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID");
```

Comment: "Ex. 1" will not compile. There is no `Builder()` function [on `NotificationCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat).

Comment: Ex.1 compiles and runs, I don't understand why I thought the mismatched types would have prevented.

Comment: It should compile with my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines are ultimately the same if you build the builder

One reason you'd keep a builder as a variable is if you need to conditionally set a value on it

```
NotificationCompat.Builder myNotificationBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID");
if (foo) myNotificationBuilder.setBar("xyz");  // for example 
Notification n = myNotificationBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Is the Notification n used for the NotificationManager?

Comment: I'm not sure. Where were these examples you've copied? How do they use notification objects?

Comment: I've been using codinginflow, 
https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/notifications-notification-channels/part-4-bigpicturestyle-mediastyle

Comment: Yeah, in that video, it's passed to the manager notify method

Comment: Did you notice that he use mismatched types in that example?

Comment: I only watched 5 seconds, but he doesn't. Theres maybe 10 lines of a builder, it ends with build method, which returns a notification object

Comment: If there's no red error lines, then his/your code is fine

Comment: I wasn't worried about the error was more curious to why that is.